# Using the .value method to get user input from the DOM (Basic Javascript Timer)

Tags: javascript

I'm making a basic javascript timer. At present the number of seconds the timer runs for is set using a variable. I'd like to have this variable to be set by the user but I'm struggling to make it work.

Here's what I've tried:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="How many seconds?" id="set-timer">
```

This gives an input box.

JS:

```
var originalCount = document.getElementById("set-timer").value;
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Am I using .value incorrectly?

Here's my JSfiddle to give you an idea of what I'm trying to achieve: https://jsfiddle.net/k0xxzkr2/1/

Hopefully I'm clear enough in my objectives. I'm still wrapping my head around Javascript.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This line is probably executing on page load, before you actually put anything in the text box:

    var originalCount = document.getElementbyId("set-timer");

You need to move this somewhere else and trigger it on an event. Maybe create another button called Set Timer

Comment: Ahah! This has fixed it for me. Thanks @dave823 ! Got it working with another button. Here's the jfiddle in case you're interested: https://jsfiddle.net/yknxk8vt/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is case sensitive. You have `getElementbyId` rather than `getElementById`. Also, you need to modify when the javascript to check the value is being run. Right now it is running on page load. You probably want to put it inside the click method of a button or something:

```js
function getInputValue() {
  // Use getElementById, not getElementbyId
  var originalCount = document.getElementById("set-timer").value;
  console.log(originalCount);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="How many seconds?" id="set-timer"> 
<button onclick="getInputValue()">Get timer value</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `getElementById` not `getElementbyId`

```
var originalCount = document.getElementById("set-timer").value;
console.log(originalCount);
```

Comment: Hi. My mistake, that was a typo. Even with the correct getElementById it still doesn't seem to work.